# How to disable newrelic_rpm on Rails AMP page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newrelic, amp-html

The AMP validator says "The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms.".

Now I know this tag 'script' is automatically created by newrelic_rpm.

My problem is that how I can disable newrelic_rpm on AMP page.

The URL of my AMP page is like `http://example.com/foo/bar.amp`.

So I tried settings like this config/newrelic.yml:

```
common: &default_settings
  license_key: foobarfoobarfoobarfoobar

  app_name: Foobar

  rules.ignore_url_regexes: ["amp", ".*amp"]

development:
  <<: *default_settings
  app_name: FooBar (Development)

  developer_mode: true
```

But it doesn't work.

My project environment:

- rails (4.1.8)
- ruby (2.2.3)
- newrelic_rpm (3.14.0.305)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did the same thing.  Small tweaks to @Awjecc's answer

```
ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :ignore_newrelic, :if => :amp_request?

   ...


  private

  def ignore_newrelic
    NewRelic::Agent.ignore_transaction
    NewRelic::Agent.ignore_apdex
    NewRelic::Agent.ignore_enduser
  end

  def amp_request?
    request.format.try(:amp?)
  end

end
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to allow your other controllers to use `amp_request?` though, no?

Comment: Other controllers usually inherit from ApplicationController and should have access to that method

Comment: `private` methods aren't accessible from inheriting/child classes. This is why you usually use `protected` methods instead.

Comment: Yes, to use the `amp_request?` method in another controller it couldn't be private - it could be protected.

Answer (score 4):

I solved myself.

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :before_amp,
                if: -> { request.path_parameters[:format] == 'amp' }

  private

  def before_amp
    NewRelic::Agent.ignore_transaction
    NewRelic::Agent.ignore_apdex
    NewRelic::Agent.ignore_enduser
  end
end
```

I'll keep this question for someone troubled with same situation.